# Adding residual standard error(standard error of the regression) to regression output table using modelsummary package in R

Tags: r, output, regression, modelsummary

I recently started using the modelsummary package in R.

By default, the modelsummary regression output displays RMSE. I could not specifically add `Residual standard error` row to the goodness of fit part of the regression table.

Reproducable example created on 2023-12-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org):

```r
library(modelsummary)

reg1 <- lm(mpg ~ disp, data = mtcars)
summary(reg1)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = mpg ~ disp, data = mtcars)
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
#> -4.8922 -2.2022 -0.9631  1.6272  7.2305 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#> (Intercept) 29.599855   1.229720  24.070  < 2e-16 ***
#> disp        -0.041215   0.004712  -8.747 9.38e-10 ***
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 3.251 on 30 degrees of freedom
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.7183, Adjusted R-squared:  0.709 
#> F-statistic: 76.51 on 1 and 30 DF,  p-value: 9.38e-10

sqrt(sum(reg1$residuals^2) / reg1$df.residual) # Residual standard error
#> [1] 3.251454
sqrt(sum(reg1$residuals^2) / nobs(reg1))       # RMSE
#> [1] 3.148207

modelsummary(reg1, output = "markdown")
```

|  | (1) |
| --- | --- |
| (Intercept) | 29.600 |
|  | (1.230) |
| disp | -0.041 |
|  | (0.005) |
| Num.Obs. | 32 |
| R2 | 0.718 |
| R2 Adj. | 0.709 |
| AIC | 170.2 |
| BIC | 174.6 |
| Log.Lik. | -82.105 |
| F | 76.513 |
| RMSE | 3.15 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [Modelsummary documentation](https://modelsummary.com/vignettes/modelsummary_extension.html#modifying-information-tidy_custom-and-glance_custom), this should work:

```r
library(modelsummary)

reg1 <- lm(mpg ~ disp, data = mtcars)

glance_custom.lm <- function(x, ...) {
  rse <- sqrt(sum(residuals(x) ^ 2) / x$df.residual)
  data.frame(RSE = format(rse, digits = 2))
}

modelsummary(reg1)
```

|  | (1) |
| --- | --- |
| (Intercept) | 29.600 |
|  | (1.230) |
| disp | -0.041 |
|  | (0.005) |
| Num.Obs. | 32 |
| R2 | 0.718 |
| R2 Adj. | 0.709 |
| AIC | 170.2 |
| BIC | 174.6 |
| Log.Lik. | -82.105 |
| F | 76.513 |
| RMSE | 3.15 |
| RSE | 3.3 |

<sup>Created on 2023-12-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>